# How to update a value using Laravel migrations?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to add 1 to all the values in a table. I am doing this:

```
public function up()
{
    DB::table('mytable')
        ->update([
            'amount' => amount + 1,
        ]);
}
```

the above code does not work. How should I refer to a value (amount) using migrations?

Comment: it should be Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To increment or decrement a column value using Laravel's query builder, you can use the method `increment()` and `decrement()`.

E.g.:

```
DB::table('mytable')->increment('amount');
```

This is documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#increment-and-decrement).

Not sure if doing it on a migration is the wisest thing. I would reserve migrations to schema changes, not to data changes.

Comment: this works, however I was looking to make some more complicated operation so I ended up using ->update(['amount' => DB::raw()]);

Answer (score 0):

You can try this like way

```
public function up(){

    DB::table('mytable')
       ->update([
           'amount' => $amount++,
       ]);
}
```